# Is this invariant correct?

Tags: dafny

I'm trying to calculate the maximum element of a sequence of naturals in dafny iteratively and I get an error in the loop's invariant.

Could someone tell me which would be the correct invariant for the code?

This is the code:

```
function maximo (s:seq<nat>):nat
  decreases |s|
{
  if s == [] then 0 else if s[0] > maximo(s[1..]) then s[0] else maximo(s[1..])
}

method maximo_it (s:seq<nat>) returns (max: nat) 
  ensures max == maximo(s);
{
  max :=0;
  var i:=0;

  while i < |s|
  decreases |s|-i
  invariant 0<=i<=|s|
  invariant max == maximo(s[..i])
  { 
    
    if (max < s[i]) { max:=s[i];}
    i:=i+1;
  }    
}
```

I tried to change it but I do think mi solution is correct. I´ve seen a possible solution that goes across the sequence from the end to the beginning, my solution is just the same but starting from the zero position.

Here is the solution's code:

```
method maximo_it (s:seq<nat>) returns (max: nat) 
  ensures max == maximo(s);
{
  
  max := 0;
  var i := |s|;
    while i > 0
    decreases i
    invariant 0 <= i <= |s|
    invariant max == maximo(s[i..]) 
    {  
        i := i-1; 
        if s[i] > max
      { 
        max := s[i];
      }
     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a lemma, another option in this case is to tweak the `maximo()` function itself.  This is the cleanest solution I came up with:

```dafny
function maximo(s:seq<nat>, n: nat):(r:nat)
requires n <= |s|
decreases n
{
    if n == 0 then 0
    else
        var last := s[n-1];
        var max := maximo(s,n-1);
        if last >= max then last
        else max
}

method maximo_it(s:seq<nat>) returns (max: nat)
ensures max == maximo(s,|s|);
{
  max :=0;
  var i:=0;

  while i < |s|
  decreases |s|-i
  invariant i <= |s|
  invariant max == maximo(s,i)
  {
    if max <= s[i] { max := s[i]; }
    i:=i+1;
  }
}
```

Here, I've reworked the order of iteration for the `maximo()` function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write the iterative code in a different order than the function, then you need a lemma to show that the two orders agree.

```
function maximo(s: seq<nat>): nat
  decreases |s|
{
  if s == [] then
    0
  else if s[0] > maximo(s[1..]) then
    s[0]
  else
    maximo(s[1..])
}

lemma maximo_unroll(s: seq<nat>)
  requires s != []
  ensures maximo(s) == if s[|s|-1] > maximo(s[..|s|-1]) then s[|s|-1] else maximo(s[..|s|-1])
{
  if s != [] {
    var butlast := s[..|s|-1];
    var rest := s[1..];
    if butlast != [] {
      maximo_unroll(rest);
      assert rest[..|rest|-1] == s[1..|s|-1];
    }
  }
}

method maximo_it (s: seq<nat>) returns (max: nat) 
  ensures max == maximo(s);
{
  max := 0;
  var i := 0;

  while i < |s|
    decreases |s| - i
    invariant 0 <= i <= |s|
    invariant max == maximo(s[..i])
  { 
    maximo_unroll(s[..i+1]);
    assert s[..i+1][..|s[..i+1]|-1] == s[..i];

    if (max < s[i]) {
      max := s[i];
    } 
    i := i+1;
  }
  assert s == s[..|s|];
}
```